# Count occuriences depending on condition & save in new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am relatively new to pandas / python.
I have a list of names and dates. I want to group the entries by Name and count the number of Names for 'after 2016' and 'before 2016'. The count should be added to a new column.

My input:

```
Name    Date
Marc    2006
Carl    2003
Carl    2002
Carl    1990
Marc    1999
Max     2016
Max     2014
Marc    2006
Carl    2003
Carl    2002
Carl    2019
Marc    1999
Max     2016
Max     2014
```

And the output, should look like this:

```
      Before
      2016  Count
Marc    1    4
Marc    0    0
Carl    1    5
Carl    0    1
Max     1    2
Max     0    2
```

So the Output should have 2 entries for each Name, one with a count of Names before 2016 and one after. Addtionally a column which just stats 1 for before 2016 and 0 for after.

As mentioned before, I am quite a beginner. I was able to count the entries with the condition of the year:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x<'2016').sum()).reset_index(name='count')
```

But honestly, I am not quite sure what to do next. Maybe somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to `apply` a function which returns a 2x2 dataframe. Something like this:

```
def counting(x):
    bef = (x < 2016).sum()
    aft = (x > 2016).sum()
    return pd.DataFrame([[1, bef], [0, aft]], index=[x.name, x.name], columns=["before 2016", "Count"])

ddf = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(counting).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

`ddf` is:

```
      before 2016  Count
Carl            1      5
Carl            0      1
Marc            1      4
Marc            0      0
Max             1      2
Max             0      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If the dataframe isn't 2x2, but I want additinional columns (for example an 'Other' column), which should be untouched but included in the new datafame ddf. Is it possible to add this information to the output? I tried to add it using ddf['Other'] = df.transform('Other'), but that results in only NaN values.

Comment: `'Other'`cannot be untouched. The resulting dataframe will not have the same size, you need to define an operation for this new column too.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by an external series having the same length as the dataframe:

```
s = df['Date'].lt(2016).astype('int')
s.name = 'Before 2016'

df.groupby(['Name', s]).count()
```

Result:

```
                  Date
Name Before 2016      
Carl 0               1
     1               5
Marc 1               4
Max  0               2
     1               2
```

`lt` stands for "less than". Other comparison functions are `le` (less than or equal), `gt` (greater than), `ge` (greater than or equal) and `eq` (equal)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you need to populate both `1` and `0` for each names, try with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
(df.assign(Before=df['Date'].lt(2016).view('i1'))
 .pivot_table('Date','Name','Before',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0).unstack()
 .sort_index(level=1).reset_index(0,name='Count'))
```

---

```
       Before  Count
Name               
Carl       0      1
Carl       1      5
Marc       0      0
Marc       1      4
Max        0      2
Max        1      2
```